# Monitor shows strange lines on moving objects

Tags: display, resolution, anti-aliasing, high-resolution, lg-monitor

Recently I often see strange lines around "edges" of objects in moving images on mainly YouTube. I can't find what it is and how to fix it.

My screen is at 60HZ and has a resolution of 2560 * 1080.
Monitor type: LG 34WK500-P

(At 75 Hz the problem is the same), I have already set the screen to factory settings but the problem is still there.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUz_9rHxJVmezJ63TR8b4AMzIWHZYyXz/view
Photo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CIoDkTRiPPZdBUwKi0bQ2JebTgJwPaFi/view

I am using the original HDMI cable (which was supplied with the monitor).
I have tried both HDMI ports but the result are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is a [moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern), caused by converting a video from its resolution to fit the native screen resolution. There are display settings that purposely blur sharp lines to a lesser or greater extent to help avoid the issue. Try adjusting the [ClearType](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-text-easier-read-using-cleartype-windows-10) settings in Windows, for example.

Comment: Ah okay I see thanks! But are there any more settings I can adjust to decrease this effect. Beceause I do see it in a lot of YouTube videos. I did the ClearType settings but this is for sure not enough to decrease the effect. Do you know any more things I can do especially for videos?

Comment: Try to find videos in the *native resolution* of your display, If you can't match it exactly, then view 1080p videos with full vertical resolution, but with blank space on the sides (2560 px display - 1920 px video = 640 px left over).

Comment: Mmmh okay but there is no other way to "fix" this problem?